# Is it valid to use 'Object' as mongoose schema type?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have faced some issues storing a json object inside mongodb with mongoose .
My debugging lead to the mongoose schema{making changes in the schema made it work but not as desired} .

So i went online and looked at how to save json object to a document, I've found many of answers regarding saving an object with fixed properties but i couldn't find many answeres about saving an object with changing properties . Some answeres here on 'stack overflow' used Object as schema type but those answeres were out of context so there wasn't enough information about it to know if it's valid or not .

It's very important to mention that on the [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) Object is not a schema type .

```
mongoose.Schema({key: {type: Object}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is as far as I know. I always use it and never got any problems.

Comment: Hello, I hope there was further more information about this subject. Anyway i'll take your experience and will keep on trying to use 'Object' and see how it goes . Thanks, Afik.